# matrix norm equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've come across the following equality in a Linear Algebra book:

For nonsingular $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} $, and  $w \in \mathbb{C}^n $

$$\max_{w} \frac{\|w\|}{\|Aw\|}=\max_{w} \frac{\|A^{-1}w\|}{\|w\|}$$

The norm mentioned is $L_2$ norm.

As simple as this equality may look, I don't seem to find the justification for it and I'm asking for a more detailed proof for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if we have $w' = \mathbf{A}w$, then we have $\mathbf{A}^{-1}w'=w$, so:

$$\max_{w'}\frac{\|\mathbf{A}^{-1}w'\|}{\|w'\|}=\max_{w}\frac{\|w\|}{\|\mathbf{A}w\|}$$

But $w'$ is just a dummy variable as we range over $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, so:

$$\max_{w}\frac{\|\mathbf{A}^{-1}w\|}{\|w\|}=\max_{w}\frac{\|w\|}{\|\mathbf{A}w\|}$$

As required.